# React native require relative path file

Tags: react-native

I am trying React Native iOS and I was trying to setup project environments. I create a file called config.js so later I can just

```
import config from 'env'
```

to load the variables based on different environments.  The following is the config.js file

```
let configFile = 'dev.js'
if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  configFile = 'prod.js'
}

export default require('./env/' + configFile)
```

Somehow this won't work. the error message is:

`Requiring unknown module "./env/dev.js". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install"`

When I changed my code to the following it would not give me errors. But it is not what I wanted to do.

```
export default require('./env/dev.js')
```

So does anyone know why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, require calls are not dynamic. They are statically analyzed and bundled. So you would want something like this

```
let prodConfig = require('./env/prod.js');
let devConfig = require('./env/dev.js');

let config;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config = prodConfig;
}else {
  config = devConfig;
}

export default config;
```